# Upload de imagem sem reload da página

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Boa noite, estou fazendo upload de arquivo, está funcionando mas toda vez que envio o arquivo a página atualiza, alguém poderia dá uma dica de como resolver isso?
Estou usando angular 5.

**component.ts**

```
OnSubmit(){

    const formData = new FormData();
    const files: Array<File> = this.filesToUpload;
    for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
      formData.append("files[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
      formData.append('title' ,  this.form.get('title').value);
  }


   this.imageService.postFile(formData).subscribe(data=>{
    // Check if comment was saved to database or not
    if (!data.success) {
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-danger'; // Return error class
       this.message = data.message; // Return error message
       toast("Erro ao salvar", 4000);
     } else {
      this.messageClass = 'alert alert-success'; // Return success class
       this.message = data.message; // Return success message
       toast("Comentário criado!", 2000);

       setTimeout(() => {

            this.form.reset(); // Reset all form fields

          }, 1000);
       // Clear form data after two seconds

     }
   });
 }
 fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
  this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;

 // Show image preview
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event:any) => {
    this.imageUrl = event.target['result'];
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);
  console.log(fileInput)
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="title">Title :</label>
      <input id="title" placeholder="Title" formControlName="title">
    </div>
      <img [src]="imageUrl"  style="width:250px;height:200px">
      <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload a file..." multiple/>


   <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
 </form>
```

**service.ts**

```
 postFile(formData) {
  let headers = new Headers(); // Create headers

    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/postFile', formData)
    .map(res => res.json())
  }
```

Comment: Muito obg, funcionou colocando na função fileChangeEvent( ).

Comment: A página estava atualizando quando alterava o input file?

Comment: Não, apenas quando envia o arquivo.

Comment: É porque não entendi. A função fileChangeEvent( ) dispara o envio da imagem? Queria entender para formular uma resposta.

Comment: Não, o responsável por enviar a imagem é this.filesToUpload no qual é chamado dentro de OnSubmit(), mas por algum motivo ele atualiza a página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque `return false;` no fim da função onde é feito o envio dos arquivos que irá anular o *refresh* da página. Ex.:

```
funcao{
   // códigos aqui
   return false;
}
```